# Parse complex xml and use as a database

Tags: javascript, xml, json, html

I am getting XML structure as below and want to fetch captions "Cancel", "Ok" based on CAPTION NAME. This should be done on client side. There are number of captions which getting shown on UI. I have tried to do it by converting xml to json but that leads to many iteration.

What is best solution to do this. Taffy, xQuery

```
<MESSAGE NAME="GET_T_APP_INIT" VERSION="1.00">
  <MESSAGEAREA NAME="T.UI.DATA" VERSION="1.00">
    <DATAFIELDS>
      <ENTITIES>
        <ENTITY NAME="INTERACTION.AUTOSTART" VERSION="1.00">.....
        </ENTITY>

        <ENTITY NAME="UI.TEXT.DATA" VERSION="1.00">
        <SETS>
          <SET SORT="1" SET_ID="1" PARENT_SET_ID="" ACTION="">
            <ATTRIBUTEGROUP NAME="UI.TEXT.ITEM" KEY="" KEYVERSION="">
              <CAPTION NAME="ACTION_MENU:CANCEL">
              Cancel
              </CAPTION>
            </ATTRIBUTEGROUP>
          </SET>
          <SET SORT="2" SET_ID="2" PARENT_SET_ID="" ACTION="">
            <ATTRIBUTEGROUP NAME="UI.TEXT.ITEM" KEY="" KEYVERSION="">
              <CAPTION NAME="ACTION_MENU:OK">
              OK
              </CAPTION>
            </ATTRIBUTEGROUP>
          </SET>
        </SETS>
        </ENTITY>
      </ENTITIES>
    </DATAFIELDS>
  </MESSAGEAREA>
</MESSAGE>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to read xml

Example

http://tech.pro/tutorial/877/xml-parsing-with-jquery